# how to connect internal hard disk to laptop via usb?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

I have a seagate internal sata hard disk as well as an external sata hard disk.Can i connect the internal hard disk via the external hard disk USB cable ?

[this is the cable i have with me](http://www.stuartconnections.com/9458-large/Seagate-FreeAgent-GoFlex-USB-30-500GB-Portable-External-Hard-Drive-HDD-Black-9ZF2A2500.jpg)

Comment: Clarify what you mean by *"internal hard disk"*.  What kind of interface does it have, e.g. SATA or PATA?  What kind of power connector does it have?

Comment: More than likely that cable will only work for that external drive, you need [a generic sata to usb adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=sata+to+usb&N=-1&isNodeId=1)

Comment: You cannot connect an internal SATA HDD using just a USB cable, you need to use an external enclosure or a SATA to USB adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the part I've pointed to in the picture then you can indeed use it to connect an external hdd. It should work with all the SATA 2.5" drives but it may not work with your bigger 3.5" drives that require more power.
USB power may not be sufficient for the odd power hungry external but since the 2.5" drives are geared more towards laptops they are happy with the power that your laptops USB port passes through the cable.

[image]